# IDA Plugin to diff functions within the same binary

Tags: bin-diffing, ida-plugin

Sometimes by reversing I find several functions **within the same binary file** which look suspiciously similar. Is there a plugin/script to quickly compare them and see their differences?

P.S. I'm aware of the myriad of tools for doing binary diffing between two different binaries, for example for doing patch diffing . *This is not what I am looking for*.

Comment: You can export the raw binary data with IDA (`ALT+L` to start selection, drag to function end, `SHIFT+E` to export) and then compare using a hex editor. P.S. I know you're doing C#10; don't waste your time, those two functions are identical.

Comment: Exactly there originated the question :) Thx for your comment.

Comment: C#10? Is this a course or something?

Comment: The FlareOn challenges http://flare-on.com/

Comment: I would imagine this can be done (maybe with a bit of hacking) using existing binary diffing tools.